# Softbody animation goes haywire later in my animation

Tags: animation, soft-body

[image]
I am rendering newspapers(planes with softbodys) with a wind force field. It blows perfectly at the start but later on all the newspapers gets suck back and creates this worm.

Answer (score 0):

"Welcome to the desert of the real..." (Morpheus in "The Matrix")... :)
Enable self-collision for the simulation and increase the value of "Distance".
And: Clear the cache...
This can be done by setting the upper frame value below the lower frame value temporarily.
Don't forget to set it back to the correct range of frames you later want to animate.
It does not hurt to enter something like 1....